# Schottky Diode disadvantage as compared to usual diode

Tags: diodes, schottky

Schottky diode have a low forward voltage drop (typically \$0.15-0.45V\$) and very fast switching action, as compared to traditional diode, which typically have a \$0.7V\$ voltage drop (Silicon diodes). What is then the advantage of traditional diode as compared to Schottky diodes?

Comment: They're cheaper!

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but in one application when I used diodes for a simple bridge rectifier, traditional silicon diodes proved to be better due to their higher voltage drop, because the result was lower power dissipation in the voltage regulator.

Comment: Schottky: More costly. If you need high voltage, the Vf advantage quickly decreases (20V <10ns 1N5817 0.45V@1A 40V 1N5819 0.6V@1A vs. 400V 50ns UF4004 1.0V@1A) so it pretty much disappears by 100V. Reverse leakage can be very high, esp. at high temperatures.  Ultrafast high voltage diodes and gold doped diodes can be an advantage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Full semiconductor junction diodes have much lower reverse leakage.  Take a look at a Schottky diode datasheet, and note the reverse leakage, particularly at maximum working temperature.

Semiconductor junction diodes are also available at much higher reverse voltages.

Answer (score 7):

Schottky diodes typically have much higher reverse leakage currents than traditional diodes.

Comment: Hmm I assume the leakage current goes hand in hand with the lower barrier height.  (It takes less thermal energy to make a carrier.)